# Переопределение динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы, c++builder, динамические-массивы

Не уверен правильно ли я назвал свою проблему, ну да ладно.

```
const len = 100;
TButton* Btn[len];

void CreateBtn(int amount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Btn[i] = new TButton(Form1);
        Btn[i]->Parent = Form1;
        //---
    }
}
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    CreateBtn(5);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            delete Btn[i];
    }
    CreateBtn(4);
}
```

Оставил только самое нужное. Сейчас объясню проблему с массивом.

Сначала я в массив `Btn` заношу 5 элементов, дальше при событии `Button1Click` массив очищается и в него опять заноситься 5 элементов. Это работает.

Если при события `Button1Click` я занесу не 5, а уже меньше(4, как в коде выше) то после следующего нажатия (то есть через одно нажатие) на `Button1` я получаю ошибку **Access violation at address 00000000, Read of address 00000000**

Получается если я в первый раз в `FromCreate` занес определенное количество элементов, то дальше я уже не смогу занести меньше. Как это решить?

Comment: После `delete Btn[i];` следует обнулить указатель, иначе на следующей итерации будет попытка повторно удалить уже удаленный указатель #5, приводящая к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: а еще лучше  использовать умные указатели

Comment: `const len = 100;` - а где тип???

Comment: Ахаха я забыл тип укать, но ошибку это не выдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Использовать динамический (настоящий, задаваемый через SetLength) массив, список или вектор (последние лучше подходят по семантике)
2) FreeAndNil, чтобы обеспечить нулевой указатель после уничтожения (не решает всех проблем)
3) Использовать переменную RealCount, которая устанавливается в значение amount

Comment: Выбрал для себя третий вариант, как наиболее простой. Всё работает, спасибо